# how to import tags in wordpress from custom blog

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss

i have a custom blog wich dont have any export function so i am converting blog entries or posts according to wordpress XML format,

i have successfully imported entries along with images aswell (it was pain in a**, but somehow i managed to do it) but the problem is with tags

how can i make xml format for importing tags aswell,

**Note:** i have created some posts in wordpress with tags and exported data then i followed that xml format to make my own xml which wordpress understands, everything is goig fine except tags.

kindly help in this regard.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Have you tried [get_the_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags)?

Comment: well this function will get tags from wordpress database right ? if right then i want to import tags from outside of the wordpress into wordpress database along with posts

Comment: Yes, this function will get tags from each post. But right now i'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you making rss document so you could import it into another wordpress website?

Comment: yes i am making RSS from URL and importing that RSS into wordpress using `RSS-importer` plugin, every RSS feed contains tags along with post, so my posts are going into wordpress database correctly and i can see them on user side, but problem with tags

Comment: I think you need to edit this plugin and add it, i think this plugin haven't this option.

Comment: i am also thinking the same :-(

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to custom code this.

Comment: aaaah... did it mate... i am lovin it! very much thanks for your interest guyz

Answer (score 2):

My approach to a similar problem (converting 3rd party database to Wordpress format) was to closely examine:

http://code.google.com/p/google-blog-converters-appengine/source/browse/trunk/samples/wordpress-sample.wxr

In your case look at

```
<channel>
...
<wp:tag><wp:tag_slug>newtag</wp:tag_slug><wp:tag_name><![CDATA[NewTag]]></wp:tag_name></wp:tag>
```

this defines the tag, that you later append to blog post:

```
        <category domain="tag" nicename="newtag"><![CDATA[NewTag]]></category>
```

This blog post also explains in detail the .wxr format that defualt Wordpress importer that ships with Wordpress uses (and wordpress itself exports to): http://ipggi.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/the-wordpress-extended-rss-wxr-exportimport-xml-document-format-decoded-and-explained/

Comment: i did it mate, that was very strange that when i exported blog posts from wordpress and then imported same posts back to wordpress, everything was ok but tags in that case aswell, so i did it through custom coding, hell yeah i am loving it! thanks anyway mate!